# Wordpress convert Forward slash into Backslash

Tags: php, wordpress

I have source code of WordPress project of Linux operating system. So each file contain code with **Forward slash** ("`/`").

I am working on Windows. Here, **Backslash**("`\` ") is necessary to access any file.

Is there any way to convert Forward slash into Backslash from throughout project or any plugin present.

Comment: Are you actually having any problems? If so, can you post the relevant code please? PHP on Windows should be able to access files just fine with either back or forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) constant for this.

Comment: This is correct, sidenote. WordPress is build to respect this. Themes/Plugins might not.

Comment: Sure, but if I correctly understood @Pradip problem, he wants to list / search throughout these plugins, or themes, perhaps some internal Wordpress functions (like [get_plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins)) could help ?

Comment: That's probably what he means. But "_source code of WordPress project_" made me doubt. That's why I'm mentioning it.